# Can i run psexec on a local machine as another user who had admin rights?

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I am trying to run a batch file on a local computer as a user with admin privileges, where there is another user logged in without admin privileges.

The batch file simply tries to create a .txt file under `C:\`, it's supposed to "test" if the admin account still has admin privileges on the machine or if maybe it somehow lost it.

I tried this:

```bash
C:\\PsTools\\psexec64.exe -u domain/email -p password -h cmd /c "C:\test\asd.bat"
```

The issue here is that it tries to download "PSEXESVC", but it can't, since the user logged in is not an admin and thus the terminal is not elevated.

I tried a bunch of other psexec flags like `-s` or `-i`, but nothing seems to work.

I'm not really sure how to go about this, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using double backward slashes as path separators? Also, are you sure you need to open cmd.exe with a batch file as an argument, rather than using the batch file directly?

Comment: The double slashes were there because I copied it out of my java code. Changing the -cmd to instead open the batch file doesn't seem to change anything.